# Volume control with gestures (iOS 7+) like VLC app had

Tags: ios, volume, uipangesturerecognizer, gestures

Is it possible to implement Volume Control of iOS device with gestures (e.g. UIPanGestureRecognizer)? 
VLC app had this feature. 
I have implemented dim control already, but volume control is still missing to me. Thanks for advices.

Comment: I know only MPVolumeView can be used by Apple, but I don't want to use any view there. Gestures only.

Comment: The only way (with non-private API) is using an `MPVolumeView`, unless you are playing your media file through an `AVAudioPlayer` instance, in that case there's a `volume` property to set the player volume (relative to the system one).

Comment: @romansladecek What do you mean that `MPVolumeView` can only be used by Apple? It's a public class. Anyone can use it. I do.

Comment: sorry. I mean only this control Apple provides for developers. Btw. I use MPMoviePlayerController for playing media

Comment: How did it make VLC in their apps?

Answer (score 0):

This is how it has been done in VLC Player

```
- (void)panRecognized:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)panRecognizer
{
CGFloat panDirectionX = [panRecognizer velocityInView:self.view].x;
CGFloat panDirectionY = [panRecognizer velocityInView:self.view].y;

MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
        if (panDirectionY > 0)
            musicPlayer.volume -= 0.01;
        else
            musicPlayer.volume += 0.01;
}
```